# Check if each string in one column occurs anywhere in another column in R

Tags: r, filtering, logical-operators, any

I am working with 2 datasets in R. Let's call them df_a and df_b. df_a contains a column, let's call it "name", with string values, both official and unofficial. df_b also contains a column, also labeled "name", with string values, all of which are official. I want to create another column in df_a, let's call it "logic", with TRUE or FALSE values, TRUE if a string value from df_a$name matches with any official string value in df_b$name, FALSE if the string value does not. I do not want to write out OR statements for all the official string values since the list is too long. Logic should check for exact matches.

What would be the code structure to do this in R?

For this example, df_b$name contains names "Official Name Example AAA" to "Official Name Example ZZZ", far too many to input manually. Here is how the code would work for the first 3 names. It correctly places true values in a new "logic" column for df_a. I want to test for all df_b$name values instead of inputting each one manually.

```
df_a$logic <- ifelse(
  df_a$name=="Official Name Example AAA" |
    df_a$name=="Official Name Example AAB" |
    df_a$name=="Official Name Example AAC",
  TRUE, FALSE)
```

For this example, df_a$name may contain: "AAA", "BBB", "Official Name Example AAA", "Official Name Example AAC", "Official Name Example AAD", etc.
Therefore, this code would return the following in df_a$logic: FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, etc.
"Official Name Example AAD" couldn't be evaluated as TRUE as well as any additional value since the code only covers the first 3 official variants.
Intended results for df_a$logic would be: FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, etc.

Comment: `df_a$logic <- df_a$name %in% df_b$name`?

Comment: Side note: `ifelse(cond, TRUE, FALSE)` is just extraneous, just use `cond`, it will return exactly the same `logical` vector. (Plus, `ifelse` is not always `class`-safe, so don't use it unless you know you need to ... and then test it. Specifically, don't put `Date` or `POSIXt` objects in the yes/no arguments ... not that you're doing that here.)